# Python MongoDB execute query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the MongoDB's query:

```
mongo_query = db.transacciones.aggregate( 
{
    $project : 
    { 
        month : {$month : "$day"}, 
        year : {$year :  "$day"},
        pr_avg_rate : 1,
        pr_avg_rate_approved : 1,
        pr_numbers : 1,
        pr_numbers_approved : 1,
        pr_total_amount : 1,
        pr_total_amount_approved : 1      
    }
}, 
{
    $group : { 
        _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },
        pr_avg_rate : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate"},
        pr_avg_rate_approved : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate_approved"},
        pr_numbers : {$sum : "$pr_numbers"},
        pr_numbers_approved : {$sum : "$pr_numbers_approved"},
        pr_total_amount : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount"},
        pr_total_amount_approved : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount_approved"} 
    }
})
```

and I'm trying to execute with Pymongo, but doesn't work and the Error is:

```
Error: connection not established pipeline must be a list
```

The Function that make the work is:

```
def execute_agregation(self, query, collection_name):
    result = None
    try:
        collection = self._instance.db[collection_name]
        result = collection.aggregate(query)
        print(result)
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error: connection not established {}'.format(error))
        return None
    else:
        return result
```

Which is called with the next instruction:

```
result = mongo_conn.execute_agregation(mongo_query, "transacciones")
```

mongo_conn is an instance of a class called Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregation pipeline needs to be set up as a list of stages. So using square brackets to denote arrays in JSON.

```
mongo_query = db.transacciones.aggregate([ 
{
    $project : 
    { 
        month : {$month : "$day"}, 
        year : {$year :  "$day"},
        pr_avg_rate : 1,
        pr_avg_rate_approved : 1,
        pr_numbers : 1,
        pr_numbers_approved : 1,
        pr_total_amount : 1,
        pr_total_amount_approved : 1      
    }
}, 
{
    $group : { 
        _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },
        pr_avg_rate : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate"},
        pr_avg_rate_approved : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate_approved"},
        pr_numbers : {$sum : "$pr_numbers"},
        pr_numbers_approved : {$sum : "$pr_numbers_approved"},
        pr_total_amount : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount"},
        pr_total_amount_approved : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount_approved"} 
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here we have two issues 
1. We need to define aggregate pipeline into stages using square bracket as suggested @Mahesh Nayak

```
mongo_query = db.transacciones.aggregate([
{
    $project : 
    { 
        month : {$month : "$day"}, 
        year : {$year :  "$day"},
        pr_avg_rate : 1,
        pr_avg_rate_approved : 1,
        pr_numbers : 1,
        pr_numbers_approved : 1,
        pr_total_amount : 1,
        pr_total_amount_approved : 1      
    }
}, 
{
    $group : { 
        _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },
        pr_avg_rate : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate"},
        pr_avg_rate_approved : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate_approved"},
        pr_numbers : {$sum : "$pr_numbers"},
        pr_numbers_approved : {$sum : "$pr_numbers_approved"},
        pr_total_amount : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount"},
        pr_total_amount_approved : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount_approved"} 
    }
}])
```

2. Second Issue with function you are passing collection name and query but query already a mongodb cursor.

either you have to modify your query as below

```
query = [
{
    $project : 
    { 
        month : {$month : "$day"}, 
        year : {$year :  "$day"},
        pr_avg_rate : 1,
        pr_avg_rate_approved : 1,
        pr_numbers : 1,
        pr_numbers_approved : 1,
        pr_total_amount : 1,
        pr_total_amount_approved : 1      
    }
}, 
{
    $group : { 
        _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },
        pr_avg_rate : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate"},
        pr_avg_rate_approved : {$avg : "$pr_avg_rate_approved"},
        pr_numbers : {$sum : "$pr_numbers"},
        pr_numbers_approved : {$sum : "$pr_numbers_approved"},
        pr_total_amount : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount"},
        pr_total_amount_approved : {$sum : "$pr_total_amount_approved"} 
    }
}]

#Or modify your function as below 
def execute_agregation(self, query):
    result = None
    try:
        result = query
        print(result)
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error: connection not established {}'.format(error))
        return None
    else:
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mahesh Nayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12333417/mahesh-nayak) and [Anil Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329176/anil-kumar-gupta), I got an approximate solution for the function **execute_agregation**:

```
def execute_agregation(self, query, collection_name):
    result = None
    try:
        collection = self._instance.db[collection_name]
        pipeline = [
            {
                "$project" : 
                { 
                    "month" : {"$month" : "$day"}, 
                    "year" : {"$year" :  "$day"},
                    "pr_avg_rate" : 1,
                    "pr_avg_rate_approved" : 1,
                    "pr_numbers" : 1,
                    "pr_numbers_approved" : 1,
                    "pr_total_amount" : 1,
                    "pr_total_amount_approved" : 1      
                }
            }, 
            {
                "$group" : { 
                    "_id" : {"month" : "$month" ,"year" : "$year" },
                    "pr_avg_rate" : {"$avg" : "$pr_avg_rate"},
                    "pr_avg_rate_approved" : {"$avg" : "$pr_avg_rate_approved"},
                    "pr_numbers" : {"$sum" : "$pr_numbers"},
                    "pr_numbers_approved" : {"$sum" : "$pr_numbers_approved"},
                    "pr_total_amount" : {"$sum" : "$pr_total_amount"},
                    "pr_total_amount_approved" : {"$sum" : "$pr_total_amount_approved"} 
                }
            }
        ]
        # print(pipeline)
        result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
        # print(result)
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error: connection not established {}'.format(error))
        return None
    else:
        return result
```

But Now, I'm trying to use the variable named query which is a string with the following structure:

```
"{'$project': {'month': {'$month': '$day'}, 'year': {'$year': '$day'}, 'pr_avg_rate': 1, 'pr_avg_rate_approved': 1, 'pr_numbers': 1, 'pr_numbers_approved': 1, 'pr_total_amount': 1, 'pr_total_amount_approved': 1}}, {'$group': {'_id': {'month': '$month', 'year': '$year'}, 'pr_avg_rate': {'$avg': '$pr_avg_rate'}, 'pr_avg_rate_approved': {'$avg': '$pr_avg_rate_approved'}, 'pr_numbers': {'$sum': '$pr_numbers'}, 'pr_numbers_approved': {'$sum': '$pr_numbers_approved'}, 'pr_total_amount': {'$sum': '$pr_total_amount'}, 'pr_total_amount_approved': {'$sum': '$pr_total_amount_approved'}}}"
```

And I want to put the query inside pipeline array like

```
pipeline = [query]
```

but it does't work right now, on this way.